# how to know if my database relationship is/isnot ok?

Tags: database, table-relationships

how can i find out if my database design (specially relationships) are ok?
i found some database examples on the internet and tried to solve them but my design is always different than the examples design.
is there a any rules to follow when designing relationships or any questions to ask myself to find out if my relations are bad? or is it possible for a database to have more than one OK design?
thanks

Comment: The simple answer: experience, along with absorbing best practices you encounter in vetted code, such as what you see in reputable projects.  Do you have a specific design question that you're mulling over?

Comment: To tell if "your database relationship is OK", update your facebook status to say you're "in a relationship" with your database, and see how long it takes for your database to change its status too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has his/her own styles in database design. What you see on the internet are also good but that is their own interpretation of the business rules given to them. You would know if your database design is okay if there is no redundancy in your data or maybe lesser than it should have been. Efficient and would be easy to call using your queries. but if you want to know what the common mistakes in designing are, then here is a link for you

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/

Answer (score 1):

In general, you use experience an follow the normal rules for normmalisatiojn or not (depending on usage).

It is toally ok for one domain toh avem ultiple solutionss, often with different performance aspects or maintenaance / expansion aspects.

Buy some good books. Ge tthe Data Model Resource Book, Volume 1, for some really good examples of how o solve standard issues (accounting, tracking stock, address management etc.).

And remember, this is 2012 and the internet is full of idiots - a lot of the examples you see would get üpeople fired for incompetence.